# Transferring two queries from MySQL syntax to PostgreSQL (tt-rss related)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm having some trouble with my tt-rss install - my DB got too big, so now purging is not working.

I've found a manual solution, but the query is for MySQL and i'm using PostgreSQL, so it's not working.

It's some kind of join, but my rudimentary SQL knowledge is not helping me, and after trying to fight with documentation, here i am :)

The query in question:

```
DELETE from ttrss_user_entries USING ttrss_entries, ttrss_user_entries 
WHERE id = ref_id 
  AND date_entered < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
  AND marked = false;
```

The second one (which i guess is deleting the leftover things in ttrss_entries):

```
DELETE FROM ttrss_entries 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(int_id) 
       FROM ttrss_user_entries 
       WHERE ref_id = id) = 0;
```

Thank you in advance :)

/Edit

Sorry, haven't thought that without the structure it's hazy :D

So, ttrss_entries looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ttrss_entries
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  title text NOT NULL,
  guid text NOT NULL,
  link text NOT NULL,
  updated timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  content text NOT NULL,
  content_hash character varying(250) NOT NULL,
  cached_content text,
  no_orig_date boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  date_entered timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  date_updated timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  num_comments integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  comments character varying(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  plugin_data text,
  author character varying(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  CONSTRAINT ttrss_entries_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT ttrss_entries_guid_key UNIQUE (guid)
)
```

and ttrss_user_entries:

```
CREATE TABLE ttrss_user_entries
(
  int_id serial NOT NULL,
  ref_id integer NOT NULL,
  uuid character varying(200) NOT NULL,
  feed_id integer,
  orig_feed_id integer,
  owner_uid integer NOT NULL,
  marked boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  published boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  tag_cache text NOT NULL,
  label_cache text NOT NULL,
  last_read timestamp without time zone,
  score integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  last_marked timestamp without time zone,
  last_published timestamp without time zone,
  note text,
  unread boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  CONSTRAINT ttrss_user_entries_pkey PRIMARY KEY (int_id),
  CONSTRAINT ttrss_user_entries_feed_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (feed_id)
      REFERENCES ttrss_feeds (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT ttrss_user_entries_orig_feed_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (orig_feed_id)
      REFERENCES ttrss_archived_feeds (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT ttrss_user_entries_owner_uid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (owner_uid)
      REFERENCES ttrss_users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT ttrss_user_entries_ref_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ref_id)
      REFERENCES ttrss_entries (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I don't want to mess with the original queries above, because i'm not entirely sure in my grasp of things, and i may change something important :)

/Edit2

I'm having success with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM ttrss_user_entries
JOIN ttrss_entries ON (ref_id = id)
WHERE ttrss_entries.author = 'something';
```

But this query is showing columns from both tables, so i'm not sure if this will delete things from both tables or not o_O'

Also `ttrss_entries.date_entered < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)` is giving me trouble: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "14"`

Comment: Can you please post the table structure?

Comment: Can you please show fully qualified field names (e.g use correlation names ("aliases") for them ) ? For instance: I cannot tell where the `id` and `ref_id` stem from, they could come from ttrss_user_entries or ttrss_entries.

Comment: The post above is updated. I've made some headway, so there's another question at the bottom :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first delete query:

```
DELETE FROM ttrss_user_entries dd
WHERE dd.marked = false
AND EXISTS (
     SELECT *
       FROM ttrss_entries ex
      WHERE ex.id = dd.ref_id
        AND ex.date_entered < now() - '14 day'::interval
      );
```

And this is the second delete:

```
    -- remove unreferenced rows from _entries
DELETE FROM ttrss_entries dd
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT *
       FROM ttrss_user_entries nx
       WHERE nx.ref_id = dd.id
        );
```

Update:  posgres also supports  the (non-standard) `USING` syntax, which is basically a `JOIN`. It is almost similar to the mysql syntax; just replace the comma by `USING`, and remove the double entry for the target table. This is for the first delete:

```
DELETE FROM ttrss_user_entries dd
USING ttrss_entries ex
WHERE ex.id = dd.ref_id
AND dd.marked = false
AND ex.date_entered < now() - '14 day'::interval
      ;
```

Final query:

```
SELECT tue.* FROM ttrss_user_entries tue
JOIN ttrss_entries te ON tue.ref_id = te.id
WHERE te.author = 'something'
  ;
```

Or (a bit clearer, and avoiding things to be listed twice (if the 1:N were the other way round)):

```
SELECT *
FROM ttrss_user_entries tue
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM ttrss_entries te
  WHERE te.id = tue.ref_id
  AND te.author = 'something'
  ;
```

Comment: Thank you, those worked. :)

Another quick question: you are setting dd and ex like aliases for the two tables or it's something else?

Comment: Yes, they are aliases. (They were lacking from your OQ, which made it hard to read, at least for me)

Comment: Ah, i see. Well, now i have more insight in joins and postgresql:) Thank you, it was really helpful.